# GitHub pages no carga datos en archivo en formato JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, github-pages

estoy desarrollando una pequeña app con JavaScript y jQuery donde para realizar unos cálculos tomo unos valores declarados en un archivo formato JSON, el código funciona sin problemas de manera local pero al hacer el deploy obtengo el siguiente error,

[image: Error en consola]

dejo adjunto el [repositorio en GitHub](https://github.com/mauropandolfo/JavascriptCoderHouse) por si desean consultarlo, es algo que pueda solucionarlo? o es normal que pase esto en github pages?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

acabo de solucionarlo, el error se debe a que el archivo JSON debe estar publicado en un servidor con https según tengo entendido, creando un repositorio, subiendo el archivo json y publicando una pagina de hithub, y luego llamando con ajax a esa url funciona sin problemas

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema... tengo subidos los JSON en mi repositorio en ua carpeta llamada /json y cuando accedia con fetch me mandaba error 404. Lo que hice fue obtener el enlace RAW del archivo desde el mismo github.

En github: Abrí el repositorio, ubiqué y abrí el archivo JSON y a la derecha hay un boton que dice RAW... luego de pulsarlo lo que queda es copiar el enlace que te da el navegador y listo. Con ese enlace pude hacer fetch.